# Static electricity repelling

Tags: electrostatics

I know that when you rub your socks on the carpet when the room is dry you will build up electrons on your body. However, what if two objects had lots of electrons (static electricity). Will the two objects repel each other? Like forces repel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually matters is the excess of protons or electrons. It determines of a body is positively charged or negatively charged. So if two bodies have like charge, then yes, they will repel each other.